# Using ng-if to add extra data onto an ng-repeat result

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<th>Subsitute</th>
<th>Card</th>
<th>Sub</th> 
<th>Goal</th> 

<tr ng-repeat="val in lineUpSub">
   <td style="width:6em">{{lineUpSub[$index]['-n']}}</td>
   <td>{{leagueTable[$index]['-name']}}</td>
   <td>{{lineUpSub[$index]['-on']}}</td>
   <td>value</td>
</tr>
```

This code displays an array which outputs football data into a leaguetable.

I need it to show an arrow (-->) every time the {{lineUpSub[$index]['-on']}} is triggered.

The array triggers numbers so I want it to be like

86 (from ng-repeat) -->

How do I do this? when the column is blank I want it to remain blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `lineUpSub[$index][-on]` return a boolean?

If so, you could simply add the following:

```
<td> {{lineUpSub[$index][-on]}} {{ lineUpSub[$index][-on] ? "-->" : "" }} </td>
```

Comment: That replaced the results with just the -->

Comment: well I'm trying to figure out what you want since the explanation ain't that clear. Maybe you need: <td> {{lineUpSub[$index]['-on']}} {{ lineUpSub[$index][-on] ? "-->" : "" }} </td>